# How to remove single value from localStorage that has same key as another value?

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I am creating a to-do list and i followed a [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AfVUiQ-my4Q) to get the items to save to local storage but now I am having trouble figuring out and understanding how to get the code to remove items from local storage. When i followed the tutorial, all the items added to local storage had the same key.
Here is some of my code:
Html:

```
<h1>My Check List App</h1>
        <h2 class="List Name"> Creating My App</h2>
        <input type="text" id="the-input" class="the-input-class" placeholder="Write your tasks here...">
        <span class="create-button">Create Task</span>
      </div>
      <ul id="the-ul" class="the-ul-list">
        <li id="the-li" class="task">Complete Sprint One</li>
        <li id="the-li" class="task">Complete Css</li>
        <li id="the-li" class="task">Finish Sprint Two</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

JavaScript:

```
//removing tasks from list
    var myList = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
    var index;
    for (index = 0; index < myList.length; index++){
      var aSpanTag = document.createElement("SPAN");
      var someTxt = document.createTextNode("\u00D7");
      aSpanTag.className = "close";
      aSpanTag.appendChild(someTxt);
      myList[index].appendChild(aSpanTag);
    }
    
    var closeButton = document.getElementsByClassName("close");
    
    for (i = 0; i < closeButton.length; i++){
      closeButton[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
        var theDiv = this.parentElement;
        theDiv.style.display = "none";
      })
    }

    //Adding tasks to localStorage
    
        const submit = document.querySelector('.create-button');
        const taskList = document.querySelector('.the-ul-list');
        const taskInput = document.querySelector('.the-input-class');
        
        function template(data){
          taskList.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", `
          <ul id="the-ul" class="the-ul-list">
            <li id="the-li" class="task">${data.task}<span class ="close">x</span></li>
          </ul>`);
        
        }
        
        
        function appendTask(event){
          const data = {
            task: taskInput.value,
          }
          event.preventDefault();
          //if comment value is smaller than 1, submit will not work
          if (taskInput.value.length < 1) return;
          template(data);
          taskInput.value ="";
          // saving the tasks to localStorage
          localStorage.setItem('taskItems', taskList.innerHTML)
        }
        submit.addEventListener('click', appendTask, false);
        
        const saved = localStorage.getItem('taskItems');
        if (saved) {
          taskList.innerHTML = saved;
        }
```

I'm sorry if the formatting is bad, this is my first time asking a question here.

Edit: Someone said i should change this to an array, how exactly would i do this with the code i currently have?

Comment: You cannot have two items in local storage with the same key. Each key has only one value associated with it. If that value is an array, it's still one array, that may have multiple elements in it.

Comment: Now you want to remove the task from localStorage, which has been closed by the user??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use array for that you to retrive the array from the localstorage then parse the data and push the new element.

```
let saved = localStorage.getItem('taskItems');
if(!saved) {
//checking if we are doing it for the firsttime
const data =  [taskList.innerHTML];
localStorage.setItem('tasksItems',JSON.stringify(data));
}
else {
 const data = JSON.parse(saved);
  saved.push(taskList.innerHTML);
  localStorage.setItem('tasksItems',JSON.stringify(data));
}
```

Comment: it seems to work, but i am getting this error in DevTools now:
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at Position 9 at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
 when I click on the error it takes me right to the top of my document to the section that reads:
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
Edit: accidently submitted before i finished comment

Comment: try this 
data = {
tasks  :  tasklist.innerHTML
}
localStorage.setItem('tasksItems',data);

Comment: i now have an error that reads

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.'
it focus on the line you suggested i change